# email composer plugin not working

Tags: cordova, email

I have added the plugin and added   as well as referenced the feature APPEmailComposer. However, when i start up the app nothing happens. I'm new to cordova.

Here is my code:

```
    <body>
        <script>

document.addEventListener('deviceready', OnDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log ('Device is ready');
}

function initialize(){

cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
    function (isAvailable) {
        // alert('Service is not available') unless isAvailable;
    }
);

cordova.plugins.email.open({
    to:          Array, // email addresses for TO field
    cc:          Array, // email addresses for CC field
    bcc:         Array, // email addresses for BCC field
    attachments: Array, // file paths or base64 data streams
    subject:    String, // subject of the email
    body:       String = "1. Take Photo with Camera" + System.lineSeparator() + "2." +System.lineSeparator() + "3." // email body 
    isHtml:    Boolean, // indicates if the body is HTML or plain text
}, callback, scope);
};

        </script>
        <button onclick ="initialize();"> Email </button>

    </body>
```

Comment: Plugin invocation code should be placed within ondevice ready function

Comment: would u plz show me the rewritten code? thx

Comment: any console error  ?

Comment: <button id="email">...</button>   function onDeviceReady() {  
     $('#email').click( function() 
  {cordova.plugins.email.open({
  to: Array, // email addresses for TO field
  cc:  Array, // email addresses for CC field
  bcc: Array, // email addresses for BCC field
  attachments: Array, // file paths or base64 data streams
  subject: String, // subject of the email
  body: String = "1. Take Photo with Camera" + System.lineSeparator() + "2." +System.lineSeparator() + "3." // email body isHtml:    Boolean, // indicates if the body is HTML or plain text
 }, callback, scope);
  });}

Comment: still not working Gandhi and Hassan, no console errors or logs

Comment: @P.Kwong You gotta share the project in github to debug further. Let me see if can quickly come up with sample app